# JPA connect foreign keys with same name

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

let's suppose I have:

1. Table **editors** (id, business_name, vat)
2. Table **authors** (id, name, email)
3. Table **books** (id, title, description, fk_author, fk_editor).

Let's say **fk_editor** is the foreign key for the id field of table editors and **fk_author** is the foreign key for the id field of table authors.

Let's say the relation **books:authors** is **n:1** and **books:editors** is **n:1**.

The question is: how to join the three tables **through books** table? 
That means, what code do I have to add in Book class to let Hibernate understand ho to create a relation with authors and editors? Consider that I have same id field name in authors and editors.
Here it's the example code I need to correct:

table **authors**:

```
package com.bytecode.jpaexample.SpringBootMySqlJpaRestExample;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "authors")
public class Author implements Serializable{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id")
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private int id;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;

   @Column(name = "surname")
   private String surname;

   @Column(name = "email")
   private String email;

   /* constructors and getters and setters omitted intentionally */

}
```

table **editors**:

```
package com.bytecode.jpaexample.SpringBootMySqlJpaRestExample;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "editors")
public class Editor implements Serializable{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id")
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private int id;

   @Column(name = "business_name")
   private String businessName;

   @Column(name = "vat")
   private String vat;

   /* constructors and getters and setters omitted intentionally */

}
```

table **books**:

```
package com.bytecode.jpaexample.SpringBootMySqlJpaRestExample;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name="books")
public class Book implements Serializable{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "id")
   private int id;

   @Column(name = "title")
   private String title;

   @Column(name = "description")
   private String description;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)      
   @JoinColumn(name = "id") //authors.id                
   @Column(name = "fk_author")
   private int fk_editor;

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)      
   @JoinColumn(name = "id") //editors.id                
   @Column(name = "fk_editor")
   private int fk_editor;

   /* constructors and getters and setters omitted intentionally */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things:

The `Author` and `Editor` classes should not have their `id` fields annotated with `@OneToMany`:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
```

Instead, I'm guessing you want another field in each class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "authors")
public class Author implements Serializable {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Book> books;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "editors")
public class Editor implements Serializable {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "editor", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List <Book> books;
    ...
}
```

Then, you need to change the class `Book` in several ways:

- rename the fields a bit more appropriately (e.g. `fk_author` becomes `author`); these must match the `mappedBy` settings in the corresponding classes, as I have specified above)
- change the field types to the appropriate classes (e.g. `Author`), *not* the foreign key types (e.g. `int`)
- change the `@JoinColumn` annotations to specify the appropriate column in the `books` table (*not* the target table) and add `referencedColumnName` settings (although, these are optional in this case; since they will default to the single primary key field on the target entity)
- remove the `@Column` annotations

See if this makes sense:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="books")
public class Book implements Serializable {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)      
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_author", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Author author;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)      
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_editor", referencedColumnName="id")
    private Editor editor;
    ...
}
```